# Evaluate an expression for a specific case

Tags: simplifying-expressions, replacement, assumptions

I am new to Mathematica I have an hard time doing really simple stuff.

I come from a MATLAB programming environment.

I have computed an expression:

```
expr1 = Simplify[Transpose[Lf01y1new].f0];
```

This expression is:

```
{{((qt^2+qx^2+qy^2+qz^2) (qt^2 (rz vx-rx vz)+qy^2 (rz vx-rx vz)-(qx^2+qz^2) (rz vx-rx vz)-2 qy (qz ry vx-qz rx vy+qx rz vy-qx ry vz)-2 qt (qx ry vx-qx rx vy-qz rz vy+qz ry vz)))/(2 qt qy rx+2 qx qz rx-2 qt qx ry+2 qy qz ry+qt^2 rz-qx^2 rz-qy^2 rz+qz^2 rz)^2}}
```

How can I compute the expression of `expr1` when, by example `rz vx = 0`?

Comment: Maybe `expr2 = Simplify[expr1, rz vx == 0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another method similar to **m_goldberg**'s comment is to use the Mathematica command `ReplaceAll`. Note that `/.` is a shortcut for `ReplaceAll`.

I redefined the expression in your question by removing the outer curly brackets and removing one set of extraneous parenthesis from the numerator.

```
expr1 = ((qt^2 + qx^2 + qy^2 + qz^2) (qt^2 (rz vx - rx vz) + 
     qy^2 (rz vx - rx vz) - (qx^2 + qz^2) (rz vx - rx vz) - 
     2 qy (qz ry vx - qz rx vy + qx rz vy - qx ry vz) - 
     2 qt (qx ry vx - qx rx vy - qz rz vy + qz ry vz)))/(2 qt qy rx + 
   2 qx qz rx - 2 qt qx ry + 2 qy qz ry + qt^2 rz - qx^2 rz - 
   qy^2 rz + qz^2 rz)^2
```

Now replace the product `rz vx` with zero as follows

```
expr2 = expr1 /. rz vx -> 0

(* ((qt^2 + qx^2 + qy^2 + qz^2) (-qt^2 rx vz - 
     qy^2 rx vz + (qx^2 + qz^2) rx vz - 
     2 qy (qz ry vx - qz rx vy + qx rz vy - qx ry vz) - 
     2 qt (qx ry vx - qx rx vy - qz rz vy + qz ry vz)))/(2 qt qy rx + 
   2 qx qz rx - 2 qt qx ry + 2 qy qz ry + qt^2 rz - qx^2 rz - 
   qy^2 rz + qz^2 rz)^2 *)
```

If you have particular individual components to replace you might consider defining a function of all of your variables:

```
f[qt_, qx_, qy_, qz_, rx_, ry_, rz_, vx_, vz_, vy_] := 
    ((qt^2 + qx^2 + qy^2 + qz^2) (qt^2 (rz vx - rx vz) + 
      qy^2 (rz vx - rx vz) - (qx^2 + qz^2) (rz vx - rx vz) - 
      2 qy (qz ry vx - qz rx vy + qx rz vy - qx ry vz) - 
      2 qt (qx ry vx - qx rx vy - qz rz vy + 
         qz ry vz)))/(2 qt qy rx + 2 qx qz rx - 2 qt qx ry + 
    2 qy qz ry + qt^2 rz - qx^2 rz - qy^2 rz + qz^2 rz)^2
```

Now you could call the function with individual variables set to specific values.

Note that the above technique is not useful for when you want the product of two variables to be a specific value. For that case, use `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I tried to use also the method of the function described by you in the 2nd part of your answer and I encountered the 'problem' you mentioned. I think that the best way to solve my question is still the one proposed by @m_goldberg , anyway thanks a lot for the time you took writing me your answer. Now I don't know which one of you 2 to accept. :)